# creating a jar and adding to another project as a library

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jar

I have java project build and executed successfully in IntelliJ using a gradle build tool. I want to create a jar file of this project and add it to the another project so that it can use this as a library. How can I create a jar and add it to another project?

Comment: Are you attempting add the project to another gradle sub-module or are you trying to publish the jar and then pull it in to an entirely different project? If you are trying to do the latter, you need to add the [maven-publish plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html)

Comment: yes, i am trying to pull the jar entirely in a different project and I have added the maven-publish plugin in gradle as well. How can I create a jar and add manually to another gradle project as an external library? I will need all the dependecies as well in the jar.

Answer (score 3):

## *Maven Publish Plugin*

The [*Maven Publish Plugin*](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) gives you a task called `publishToMavenLocal`. If you run that task like so in the project that is the one you wish to publish:

```
./gradlew publishToMavenLocal
```

this will publish a jar that you can pull into another project, assuming you have your group, module and version setup properly.

The group property you can set in your `build.gradle`, version in the `gradle.properties` and the module will be the name of the module that is being built unless specified otherwise.

You can check in your ~/.m2 directory to see that they were published with the correct group, module, and version.

Then in your consuming module, you can specify `mavenLocal()` in your repositories dsl block, and declare your published jar that you want to consume just like any other dependency.

Comment: Can I give version in the command instead of giving it in the gradle.properties? Because i don't see gradle.properties in my project.

Comment: I think you can do something like `-Pversion=1.0.13` or whatever your version is. Or just create the `gradle.properties` file at the root level.

Comment: When I do -pversion=$my_version, it throws me "could not set unknown property 'allowInsecureProtocol' for the object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository". But I need this as I have http instead of https for repo url and can't change that to https.

Comment: I am not sure how that property might relate to other dependencies you are pulling in. The for sure way I know how to set the version is with the `gradle.properties` file, which should be in the root directory. Otherwise you would have to do some research on how that property affects other dependencies you have.